# Countdown Timer Reset Conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I'm using a countdown timer script that I've come across online and modified slightly to suit my website. This works perfectly for counting down to a set date/time but I need the timer to reset back to a 24 hour countdown when it reaches 00:00 every day. This is for a website which counts down how long is left for free shipping on products.

**This can be seen working here:**

https://zoeyplayground-com.zoeysite.com/countdown

**Here's the full code:**

(CSS then HTML below - Please note the snippet doesn't run on here)

```css
/* Countdown Timer Start */

#countdown {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
#countdown li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#countdown li span {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#countdown .seperator {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#countdown li p {
  color: #a7abb1;
  font-size: 16px;
}
/* Countdown Timer End */
```

```html
<!-- Countdown Timer Start -->

<script>
  ! function(t) {
    t.fn.countdown = function(e, n) {
      function o() {
        var t = new Date(r.date),
          e = s(),
          o = t - e;
        if (0 > o) return clearInterval(d), void(n && "function" == typeof n && n());
        var a = 1e3,
          f = 60 * a,
          u = 60 * f,
          l = 24 * u,
          c = Math.floor(o / l),
          h = Math.floor(o % l / u),
          x = Math.floor(o % u / f),
          g = Math.floor(o % f / a),
          y = 1 === c ? r.day : r.days,
          m = 1 === h ? r.hour : r.hours,
          v = 1 === x ? r.minute : r.minutes,
          D = 1 === g ? r.second : r.seconds;
        c = String(c).length >= 2 ? c : "0" + c, h = String(h).length >= 2 ? h : "0" + h, x = String(x).length >= 2 ? x : "0" + x, g = String(g).length >= 2 ? g : "0" + g, i.find(".days").text(c), i.find(".hours").text(h), i.find(".minutes").text(x), i.find(".seconds").text(g), i.find(".days_text").text(y), i.find(".hours_text").text(m), i.find(".minutes_text").text(v), i.find(".seconds_text").text(D)
      }
      var r = t.extend({
        date: null,
        offset: null,
        day: "Day",
        days: "Days",
        hour: "Hour",
        hours: "Hours",
        minute: "Minute",
        minutes: "Minutes",
        second: "Second",
        seconds: "Seconds"
      }, e);
      r.date || t.error("Date is not defined."), Date.parse(r.date) || t.error("Incorrect date format, it should look like this, 12/24/2012 12:00:00.");
      var i = this,
        s = function() {
          var t = new Date,
            e = t.getTime() + 6e4 * t.getTimezoneOffset(),
            n = new Date(e + 36e5 * r.offset);
          return n
        },
        d = setInterval(o, 1e3)
    }
  }(jQuery);
</script>

<script>
  jQuery('#countdown').countdown({
    date: '04/15/2016 21:00:00'
  });
</script>

<!-- Countdown Timer End -->

<!-- Countdown Timer Content Start -->

<ul id="countdown">
  <li><span class="hours">00&nbsp;</span>
    <p class="hours_text">Hours</p>
  </li>
  <li class="seperator">:</li>
  <li><span class="minutes">00</span>
    <p class="minutes_text">Minutes</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Countdown Timer Content End -->
```

My query is whether this requires a small amount of code within the jQuery  or whether it requires a re-write of the main script? Is there a small function I could include to change this to a reset counter?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need the timer to reset back to a 24 hour countdown when it reaches 00:00."

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear here. When the timer reaches 00:00, I need it to start again at 23:59:59 and do this each day. It's basically for a site which counts down how long is left for free shipping, if the context helps here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add this line:

```
if(h == 0 && x == 0) {
    h = 24;
}
```

after the long list of variables is calculated.

If there are 0 hours and 0 minutes left then reset hours to 24.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/km047ryb/

Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also included the console line above as this wasn't in the original code. Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, happy coding